# Cleaning up a string in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a lot of paths (as strings) in redshift among the lines of:

```
/foo/bar/abc/keyword/<random_id>/def/ghi
/bar/abc/xyz/lmn/keyword/<another_random_id>/qwe
/bar/keyword/<another_random_id>/tsf/qft
```

Notice there will always be a keyword before the randomly generated id. What I want to do is to clean them up and replace ALL the ids with a generic string, something like:

```
/foo/bar/abc/keyword/generic_string/def/ghi
/bar/abc/xyz/lmn/keyword/generic_string/qwe
/bar/keyword/generic_string/tsf/qft
```

I really don't care about the ids for this particular use case. I already have something like this:

```
select substring(column_with_strings, 0, charindex('keyword/',column_with_strings) + 8)
```

This is to get everything before the id, and:

```
select 
substring(column_with_strings,
          len(substring(column_with_strings, 0, charindex('keyword/',column_with_strings) + 9)),
          len(column_with_strings) - len(substring(column_with_strings, 0, charindex('keyword/',column) + 8)))
```

That is to get everything after that.

There has to be a better way to achieve what I want. Even with my code above I'm stuck because I don't know how to get everything after the first '/' to get rid of the id.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:** The id is not numeric, it is alphanumeric and of variable length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Amazon Redshift you can create a Python UDF for this. It's quite easier to process in Python than in SQL. The body of the function will look something like this:

```
arr = path.split('/')
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    if arr[i]=='keyword':
        arr[i+1]='generic_string'
return '/'.join(arr)
```

More about Python UDFs: [Creating a Scalar UDF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html)

Comment: Totally forgot this existed. Just had to add len(arr)-1 since the string also starts with /. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_replace` is probably the easiest way to do it, but just not that efficient.

```
regexp_replace(column_with_strings, '(/keyword/).*(/.*$)', '$1generic_string$2')
```